# Rearrange dataframe structure

Tags: python, pandas

I get a dataframe

```
df
   A  B
0  1  4
1  2  5
2  3  6
```

For further processing, it would be more convenient to have the df restructered 
as follows:

```
 letters numbers
0  A     1
1  A     2
2  A     3
3  B     4
4  B     5
5  B     6
```

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html) with [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) :

```
df = df.unstack().reset_index(level=1, drop=True).reset_index()
df.columns = ['letters','numbers']
print (df)
  letters  numbers
0       A        1
1       A        2
2       A        3
3       B        4
4       B        5
5       B        6
```

Or [`numpy.concatenate`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html) + [`numpy.repeat`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.repeat.html) + [`DataFrame`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.html):

```
a = np.concatenate(df.values)
b = np.repeat(df.columns,len(df.index))
df = pd.DataFrame({'letters':b, 'numbers':a})
print (df)
  letters  numbers
0       A        1
1       A        4
2       A        2
3       B        5
4       B        3
5       B        6
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably simplest to [`melt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.melt.html):

```
In [36]: pd.melt(df, var_name="letters", value_name="numbers")
Out[36]: 
  letters  numbers
0       A        1
1       A        2
2       A        3
3       B        4
4       B        5
5       B        6
```